# Is the launcher is responsible for drawing the wallpaper on Android?

Tags: android, wallpaper, launcher

I'm just wondering if it's the Launchers' responsibility to render the wallpaper/live wallpapers? or if's always drawn below it? so that if i make a transparent launcher i can assume that the wallpaper is there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a function of the OS and not the launcher: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/service/wallpaper/WallpaperService.html

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use the system wallpaper as your activity background, set your activity theme to Theme.Wallpaper.